Securely Injecting Google Maps API Key in Flutter (iOS & Android)
I’m currently trying to add a Google Maps API key to both iOS and Android in my Flutter app without hardcoding it, using environment variables.
To do this, I followed a guide that uses a shell script, extract-defines.sh, to decode DART_DEFINES and output the variables to an .xcconfig file. I’ve set up this script as a pre-build action in Xcode, but that didn't work.
i'm not sure how to debug this to check if the script is working or not.
shell script that should extract the dart-defines and add it to the xconfig.
#!/bin/sh

OUTPUT_FILE="${SRCROOT}/Flutter/Dart-Defines.xcconfig"

: > $OUTPUT_FILE

function decode_url() { echo "${*}" | base64 --decode; }

IFS=',' read -r -a define_items <<<"$DART_DEFINES"

for index in "${!define_items[@]}"
do
    item=$(decode_url "${define_items[$index]}")
    # Dart definitions also include items that are automatically defined on the Flutter side. 
    # However, if we export those definitions, we will not be able to build due to errors, # so we do not output items that start with flutter or FLUTTER.
    lowercase_item=$(echo "$item" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
    if [[ $lowercase_item != flutter* ]]; then
        echo "$item" >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"
    fi
done

i added this Key to Info.plist
<key>GOOGLE_MAPS_API</key> <string>$(GOOGLE_MAPS_API)</string>
now i'm trying to configure Google Maps in AppDelegate.swift using this same key
import Flutter
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

@main
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if let googleMapsApiKey = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "GOOGLE_MAPS_API") as? String {
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(googleMapsApiKey)
    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

i was mostly following the only guide i found about this online. but i think i might be missing something.
Note: i want to do this for android as well but i started with IOS and hit a wall

If your Google maps api key is embedded in a plist file in your bundle, it isn't really secure.

Then what's the best way to do this ?

You could use a server to vend the api key to your app. You can secure that transaction with app attestation and Play Integrity this also allows you to easily revoke and replace the api key periodically or if it is compromised.

From what I understand, it is unnecessary and often impossible to properly secure your map API key in this way. All mapping services, especially on the web, use a public key (often in plain text) - yes this may allow attackers to use the key to drive up the costs in theory. For example, the Mapbox API key is embedded directly into maps on many pages and does not need skill to uncover from the DevTools Network tab. However, the API key should be set up correct in Google Cloud, and budgets used to give warnings about potential attacks.
Indeed, it is much easier to properly secure the key on Android and iOS apps than on the web. In your Google Cloud credentials, find the view similar to the screenshot:

Select iOS apps - you will need a different key for Android by the looks of it - then simply add your bundle ID.

For Android, do similar, but follow the more complex instructions on the right.

You can also setup other API restrictions here to minimize the risk if the key is leaked.
